# Install John the Ripper Jumbo

Tags: terminal, install, bash, software

I've been following the [instructions here](http://gwallgofi.com/john-the-ripper-on-osx/) for installing John the Ripper on my Macbook Pro (El Capitan). I've skipped the Iterm and Cuda sections (I have a Redeon GPU).

All is well until I run

```
make clean macosx-x86-64
```

Which gives me the error:

```
gcc -c -Wall -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include     -m64 -Wno-deprecated-declarations -funroll-loops dynamic_fmt.c
In file included from dynamic_fmt.c:69:
./sha.h:4:10: fatal error: 'openssl/sha.h' file not found
#include <openssl/sha.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [dynamic_fmt.o] Error 1
make: *** [macosx-x86-64] Error 2
```

How can I get it to compile?

I've read that it is better to use CommonCrypto API instead of OpenSSL. However, I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had more luck using the latest Jumbro version (1.8.0.6).

To retrieve and compile:

```
git clone https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper jumbo
cd jumbo/src
./configure --enable-mpi
```

Note there is no need to edit the Makefile to enable the MPI any more - the above command will get everything ready for building.

```
make clean
```

Boom - everything now working.

Comment: Frick, I've been fighting with one of their releases for hours and cloning trunk worked immediately. /facepalm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the header files.  If you have brew installed you can:

```
brew install openssl libyaml libffi
```

Comment: Just tried it. However, I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Installation of John The Ripper on Catalina, as Silver was saying:

```
git clone https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper jumbo
cd jumbo/src
```

Than I had the same problem at author of the post, and solved it with the following command:

```
make -s clean && make -sj4
```

At this stage I had a problem because of the ar / ran library (for some reason Homebrew changed the default PATH, I solved the issue by moving the rogue folder altogether),

```
sudo mv /usr/local/Cellar/cctools/855/bin/ranlib /opt/local/bin/ranlib-backup-2020-03-24
sudo mv /usr/local/Cellar/cctools/855/bin/ar /opt/local/bin/ar-backup-2020-03-24
```

You will find the specific location of your "rogue ar / ranlib" folder from your logs if you have a problem.

At this point I just launched:

```
../run/john --test=0
```

And boom it works.

After the installation I had another major problem, a perl related one concerning the Lzma package, if you have the same problem this four lines of code solved it for me:

```
sudo cpan Compress::Raw::Lzma
cpan Compress::Raw::Lzma
sudo cpan IO::Compress::Lzma
cpan IO::Compress::Lzma
```

Comment: Can't you just `brew install john-jumbo` nowadays?

Comment: I tried both `brew install john`, and `john-jumbo`, however in both cases I had problems with some dependencies such as `ar`, `ranlib`, and `lzma`. In this case installing from zero appears to be actually faster (given that you have 10 commands max to have it fully working).

Comment: Another thing that might be worth to mention is the fact that JtR has two jumbo builds:
https://download.openwall.net/pub/projects/john/contrib/macosx/

From their website:
`The "avx2" one is for newer computers (and will run faster there), the
"sse4" is for older ones (and will also run on newer ones, but slower
than the "avx2" build).  Both are 64-bit builds.`

So installing manually can give you better flexibility and performance if you have an older Mac.

Comment: The issues with the dependencies seems to be more a problem of your setup then (worked without problems here). The more granular control of compile time options is a good reason though.